# Finding partial correlation with missing value

Tags: r

I want to find the partial correlation between two variables holding the third variable fix using pearson method.

This is the error I had:

> Error in if (det(cvx) < .Machine$double.eps) :missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

In fact, I have a missing value in the data and (`na.rm=T`) didn't work with me.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: for example if I have x=c(2,NA,4,5) , y=c(3,2,6,6) and z=c(12,22,14,11) how could I find the correlation between x and y holding z fixed using pcor.test function? @jruf003

Answer (score 3):

Here's a reproducible example for the OP's question:

```
library("ppcor")

varX <- seq(from=1, to=10, length=10)
varY <- seq(from=20, to=50, length=10)
varZ <- rnorm(10)

varZ[c(1,5,7)] <- NA

pcor.test(x=varX, y=varY, z=varZ)
```

> Error in if (det(cvx) < .Machine$double.eps) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

This is addressed in the documentation for the `ppcor` package (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ppcor/versions/1.1/topics/pcor.test) in the Notes Section: `Note: Missing values are not allowed`

You might look at the `partial.r()` function of the `psych` package instead.

```
library("psych")
mydata <- cbind(varX, varY, varZ)
partial.r(data=mydata, x=c("varX","varY"), y="varZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The library WGCNA can handle missing values.

```
library(WGCNA)
varX <- seq(from=1, to=10, length=10)
varY <- seq(from=20, to=50, length=10)
varZ <- rnorm(10)

varZ[c(1,5,7)] <- NA

corAndPvalue(cbind(varX, varY, varZ), method='spearman')
```

correlations with some statistics.

```
$cor
      varX  varY  varZ
varX  1.00  1.00 -0.25
varY  1.00  1.00 -0.25
varZ -0.25 -0.25  1.00

$p
             varX         varY         varZ
varX 1.063504e-62 1.063504e-62 5.887244e-01
varY 1.063504e-62 1.063504e-62 5.887244e-01
varZ 5.887244e-01 5.887244e-01 1.411089e-39

$Z
           varX       varY       varZ
varX 51.9536816 51.9536816 -0.5711204
varY 51.9536816 51.9536816 -0.5711204
varZ -0.5711204 -0.5711204 41.0729917

$t
             varX         varY         varZ
varX 1.342177e+08 1.342177e+08 5.773503e-01
varY 1.342177e+08 1.342177e+08 5.773503e-01
varZ 5.773503e-01 5.773503e-01 1.061084e+08

$nObs
     varX varY varZ
varX   10   10    7
varY   10   10    7
varZ    7    7    7
```